# Can't give multiple roles with dropdown roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a dropdown role system in discord.js version 12 and whenever I select more than one role it only gives me the first one I add.

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('clickMenu', async menu => {

        if (menu.values[0] == "quote_pings") {
          if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809011668465745940")) {
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("809011668465745940")
            return menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the quote pings role.", true)
          } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809011668465745940")){
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("809011668465745940")
            return menu.reply.send("I have given you the quote pings role!", true)
          }
        } else if (menu.values[0] == "economy_pings") {
          if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809354393413222431")) {
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("809354393413222431")
            return menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the economy pings role.", true)
          } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809354393413222431")){
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("809354393413222431")
            return menu.reply.send("I have given you the economy pings role!", true)
          }
        }  else if (menu.values[0] == "server_pings") {
          if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("772763475973242900")) {
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("772763475973242900")
            return menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the economy pings role.", true)
          } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("772763475973242900")){
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("772763475973242900")
            return menu.reply.send("I have given you the economy pings role!", true)
          }
        }   else if (menu.values[0] == "event_pings") {
          if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("828575560137572402")) {
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("828575560137572402")
            return menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the event pings role.", true)
          } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("828575560137572402")){
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("828575560137572402")
            return menu.reply.send("I have given you the event pings role!", true)
          } 
        } else if (menu.values[0] == "movie_pings") {
          if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("828575746845835305")) {
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("828575746845835305")
            return menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the event pings role.", true)
          } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("828575746845835305")){
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("828575746845835305")
            return menu.reply.send("I have given you the event pings role!", true)
          }  
        } else if (menu.values[0] == "chat_pings") {
          if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("872241962588201031")) {
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("872241962588201031")
            return menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the chat revive pings role.", true)
          } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("872241962588201031")){
            await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("872241962588201031")
            return menu.reply.send("I have given you the chat revive pings role!", true)
          }  
        }
      })
```

Whenever I get all the roles, I only get one role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only checking the first element of the `menu.values` (`menu.values[0]`). It's perfectly fine if you only allow a single one but won't work if you select more than one role. To solve this you can iterate over all the selected `value`s.

You could also simplify your code by creating a `roles` object where the keys are the menu values.

```js
client.on('clickMenu', async menu => {
  let roles = {
    quote_pings: {
      id: '809011668465745940',
      name: 'quote pings',
    },
    economy_pings: {
      id: '809354393413222431',
      name: 'economy pings',
    },
    server_pings: {
      id: '772763475973242900',
      name: 'server pings',
    },
    event_pings: {
      id: '828575560137572402',
      name: 'event pings',
    },
    movie_pings: {
      id: '828575746845835305',
      name: 'movie pings',
    },
    chat_pings: {
      id: '872241962588201031',
      name: 'chat revive pings',
    },
  }

  for (let value of menu.values) {
    let role = roles[value]
    if (!role) continue

    if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
      await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove(role.id)
      menu.reply.send(`I have removed you from the ${role.name} role.`, true)
    } else {
      await menu.clicker.member.roles.add(role.id)
      menu.reply.send(`I have given you the ${role.name} role!`, true)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are only comparing the first item of `menu.values`, by using `menu.values[0]`.  If you want to add/remove all roles, you will need to use a loop of some kind:

```js
client.on("clickMenu", async (menu) => {
  const { values } = menu;
  // Run through all values selected
  for (const value of values) {
    // Do different actions based on the current value
    // if/else if can also be used instead of a switch statement
    switch (value) {
      case "quote_pings": {
        if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809011668465745940")) {
          await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("809011668465745940");
          menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the quote pings role.", true);
        } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809011668465745940")){
          await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("809011668465745940");
          menu.reply.send("I have given you the quote pings role!", true);
        }
        break;
      }
      case "economy_pings": {
        if (menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809354393413222431")) {
          await menu.clicker.member.roles.remove("809354393413222431");
          menu.reply.send("I have removed you from the economy pings role.", true);
        } else if (!menu.clicker.member.roles.cache.has("809354393413222431")){
          await menu.clicker.member.roles.add("809354393413222431");
          menu.reply.send("I have given you the economy pings role!", true);
        }
        break;
      }
      /**
       * etc...
       */
    }
  }
});
```